# Web Scrapping using Selenium with Python Dynamically website

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am extracing the products data from different paging but it get the first page data not different page, even i added waits structure is completed loaded but still not getting the other page data.

please help me out to solve

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, StaleElementReferenceException, WebDriverException

import xlwings as xw

# Create a webdriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    # Navigate to the website
    url = 'https://www.vinted.fr/'
    driver.get(url)

    # Access the Excel file
    wb = xw.Book('D:/Salman_Projects/EbuyScraping/EbayExcel.xlsm')
    sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
    keywords = sheet.range('L5').value

    # Input keywords into the search box
    search_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'search_text'))
    )
    search_input.send_keys(keywords + Keys.RETURN)


    while True:
        # Wait for the dynamic content to be loaded
        parent_locator = (By.CLASS_NAME, 'feed-grid')
        try:
            parent_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located(parent_locator)
            )

            # Extract product information
            product_items = parent_element.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'new-item-box__container')

            for product_item in product_items:
                owner_name = product_item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'web_ui__Text__caption').text
                image_url = product_item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid$="--image--img"]').get_attribute('src')
                title = product_item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'web_ui__Text__subtitle').text

                try:
                    price_element = product_item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'web_ui__Text__price')
                    price = price_element.text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    price = "Price not available"
                # Print the extracted data for each product
                print(f"Owner: {owner_name}, Image URL: {image_url}, Title: {title}, Price: {price}")
            # Check if the "Next" button is disabled
            try:
                next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'web_ui__Pagination__next'))
                )
                next_button_classes = next_button.get_attribute('class')
                if 'web_ui__Pagination__next web_ui__Pagination__is-disabled' in next_button_classes:
                    break  # Break the loop if the "Next" button is disabled
            except NoSuchElementException:
                break  # Break the loop if the "Next" button is not found
            except TimeoutException:
                print("Timeout waiting for the 'Next' button to be clickable.")
                break
            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                print("Stale element reference while checking 'Next' button.")
                break
            except WebDriverException as e:
                print(f"WebDriverException: {e}")
                break



            # Click the "Next" button and wait for the new set of products to load
            next_button.click()

            # Additional wait for the new set of products to load
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.staleness_of(parent_element)
            )
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located(parent_locator)
            )


        except TimeoutException as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            print("Page load timed out.")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")

finally:
    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()
```

this .

I want to  extract the products data from different pages but it getting just one page data.